# Grammatical explanation of participle phrase (or gerund phrase) after verb + noun (see example)

Tags: gerunds, complements, participle-phrases, catenative-verbs

> They spend hours watching video on their phones.

In this quote, is the phrase 'watching video on their phones' a present participle phrase or a gerund? If it is a participle phrase, surely it should modify 'they' rather than 'hours' (as shown below)?

> Watching video on their phones, they spend hours.
>
> They spend hours, watching video on their phones.

Alternatively, is it a gerund that is functioning as catenative complement to the verb 'spend'?

A third and final explanation I can think of is that there is an omitted 'by' preposition (example below), explaining how the hours are spent.

> They spend hours by watching video on their phones.

I'm struggling to find an answer to this by searching the internet, as it follows the basic 'noun + participle phrase' formula. However, in my opinion (which may be wrong), it isn't that simple.

Comment: If you look up the word "spend" in the dictionary, you can grasp the sentence structure easily. In the given sentence,  a preposition "in" is omitted so the sentence is "they spend hours in watching video on their phones."

Comment: We often (usually?) don't bother with a preposition between ***spend time, waste time, pass time,...*** and a verb-based clause specifying some "time-consuming" activity. But if we ***do*** want to include a preposition, ***by, in, on, at, with, over,...*** (and probably several others) are all possible alternatives. Perhaps precisely *because* no preposition at all is usually fine, we're not particularly fixed as regards which one to use.